# In Elixir, how can a range be converted to a list?

Tags: elixir

I can declare a range as follows:

```
range = 1..10
```

Is there a way to convert the range to a list?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`Enum.to_list/1` is what you're looking for:

```
iex(3)> Enum.to_list 1..10
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: This is even better than my answer. :)

Comment: This is the fastest method (on my machine, at least). Microbenchmarks in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724310/1417451) below.

Answer (score 17):

The generic way to convert an enumerable into a specific collectable is `Enum.into`:

```
Enum.into 1..10, []
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You can also pass a transformation function as third argument:

```
Enum.into 1..10, %{}, &({&1, &1})
#=> %{1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6, 7 => 7, 8 => 8, 9 => 9, 10 => 10}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but only for empty lists. if you want to "merge" an existing list with a range Enum.into this is not the way. Could be good add this option to the answer ```List.flatten 2..5 |> Enum.to_list, [1]``` will return ```[1,2,3,4,5]```

Answer (score 10):

Use `Enum.map/2`

```
range = 1..10
Enum.map(range, fn(x) -> x end)
```

or

```
Enum.map(range, &(&1))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the pipeline operator

```
1..10 |> Enum.to_list

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and then you can apply further transformations on it like

```
1..10 |> Enum.to_list |> Enum.sum

55
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [Benchfella](https://github.com/alco/benchfella) microbenchmark comparing the approaches found in the previous answers.

```
defmodule RangeToListBench do
  use Benchfella

  @test_range 1..1000

  bench "Enum.map",     do: Enum.map(@test_range, &(&1))
  bench "Enum.to_list", do: Enum.to_list(@test_range)
  bench "Enum.into",    do: Enum.into(@test_range, [])
end
```

Here's what I get on my 2017 MacBook Pro with `@test_range` set to `1..1000`:

```
benchmark nam iterations   average time 
Enum.to_list      100000   21.97 µs/op
Enum.into         100000   23.72 µs/op
Enum.map           50000   34.72 µs/op
```

With a much larger range of `1..100_000`, the relative ordering stays the same:

```
Enum.to_list        1000   2427.21 µs/op
Enum.into           1000   2540.62 µs/op
Enum.map             500   3414.07 µs/op
```

The same goes for a much smaller range of `1..10`:

```
Enum.to_list    10000000   0.32 µs/op
Enum.into       10000000   0.32 µs/op
Enum.map        10000000   0.45 µs/op
```

**TL;DR**: `Enum.to_list/1` is probably the most efficient choice.